# How to use custom Google Assistant commands without "Let's talk to" and without IFTTT

Tags: android, iot, google-assistant-sdk, google-developers-console, google-assist-api

I know this is broad question but I've spent counless hours searching for the right solution. Google provides at least 15 different types of Google Assistant connections all of them are different and I don't know which one to use for my project. The project is pretty simple - I would like to call dynamic url with parameters (webhook to my home server) from mobile Google Assistant.Example - I would say to my Android mobile phone

```
> Ok, Google set the TV volume to 50
```

and the assistant would call

```
GET "https://192.168.1.12/tv/volume/50
```

or

```
GET "https://192.168.1.12/?device=tv&action=volume&value=50
```

where 'tv', 'volume' and '50' are the dynamic parameters (not static) so I could also call

```
> Ok, Google set the TV channel to 132
```

I just want a link or a name of the Google dev console that I can use. I don't want to waste another several hours just to find out that another Google package is not suitable for my project. Have anyone done something similar?

PS 
I know that I could achieve something similar with "Ok, Google let's talk to ...." but that is not my case.

also I CAN'T USE IFTTT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no one-click mechanism to do this directly in Assistant. The [smart home platform](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/overview) allows you to configure a service that would capture commands such as [Channel](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/traits/channel) and [Volume](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/traits/volume) and let you handle those commands in the way you want, using a cloud backend and optionally the [Local Home SDK](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/concepts/local).

This may be a bit more work than you want, and you may want to consider existing smart home platforms which may handle some of the backend work such as https://homeassistant.io which does have an Assistant integration already, though I'm less sure of whether it may work in your use case.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to answer your question without knowing your constraints. Are you a developer? Are you looking to make a commercial app? For non-commercial use you can use the [Google Assistant Service](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/guides/service/python) to create custom commands that do whatever you want (including call your API). As a benefit, you don't have to say "hey Google" before your command.

Also, it would help to know why you can't use IFTTT, given that it *seems* to do exactly what you're asking for.